# Ruby on rails Updating User roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, user-roles

I'm trying to update the role of a user from 'free' to 'premium' after they successfully make a payment.

User.rb

```
   class User < ApplicationRecord

    enum role: [:free, :premium]
    before_create :assign_default_role

      def assign_default_role
      self.role ||= :free
      end
end
```

subscriptions controller

```
def create

  @user = current_user

    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
  if @subscription.save_with_payment
    redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing"
    @user.update_attribute(role: premium )
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error undefined local variable or method `premium' after trying to make the user makes a payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want `premium` to be `:premium`? Better yet, how about:

```
@user.premium!
```

Personally, I prefer to use the form of `enum`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  enum role: {
    free:     0,
    premium:  1
  }

  before_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    self.role ||= :free
  end

end
```

For the reasons discussed in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Finally, perhaps you should consider putting a default on `role` (using a migration) so that you don't have to do that `before_create` bit.